# ¿Como guardar los datos de un SELECT Multiple en un solo campo de mi Base de Datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un select multiple y al momento de guardar los datos en mi base de datos lo hace por separado, y yo quiero que guarde los datos seleccionados en un solo campo. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
<select  multiple="multiple" size="7"  name="dias[]">
  <option value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
  <option value="Martes">Martes</option>
  <option value="Miercoles">Miercoles</option>
  <option value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
  <option value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
  <option value="Sabado">Sabado</option>
  <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
</select>
```

```
$dias = $_POST["dias"];

foreach($dias as $valor){


$sql ="INSERT INTO tabla (dias) VALUES ('$valor')"; 

$resultado = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);

if (!$resultado){

  alert("FALLO EL REGISTRO DE HORARIO");

}

else{

  alert("REGISTRO DE HORARIO CON EXITO");

}


}mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: ¿El código que publicaste tiene algún problema? ¿Podrías indicar cuál es?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

una solución que se me ocurre es que guardes un **json** del array que recibes de resultado:

```
$dias = $_POST["dias"];
$json = json_encode($dias, true);
$sql =sprintf("INSERT INTO tabla (dias) VALUES ('%s')", $json);
$resultado = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);
if (!$resultado){
    alert("FALLO EL REGISTRO DE HORARIO");
} else {
    alert("REGISTRO DE HORARIO CON EXITO");
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Con esto guardarías un `json` de los días que te han seleccionado, y luego cuando tengas que leerlo, decodificas ese campo con `json_decode`.

**Nota:** Dado que utilizas directamente la variable `$_POST`, puedes tener problemas de **inyeccion SQL**. Revisa la seguridad de tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias se resolvió mi problema!!!